# I want to make a card view for listing . But I am not getting proper view

Tags: android, listview, android-cardview, cardview

I want to make a card view for listing . But I am not getting proper view .

I want to display image in left side . on right side of image i want to display Hotel name, area ,rating,Cuisine .

But all is getting overlapping now via this code .

Can anyone help me ? I am uploading image what i am getting use of this code .

see in the image Hotel name, area ,rating,Cuisine is overlapping . how to get solve this ?
This is the screen shot what i want through card view

.[image]

[image]

list_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     >
<!--<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/list_row_selector"
    android:padding="8dp" >-->

    <!-- Thumbnail Image -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/ly_root"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FEFEFE"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="4dp">


    <!--<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">-->
    <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"  />

    <!-- Restaurant name  -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:textSize="@dimen/title"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/area"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/name"
        android:textColor="#D2691E"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:textSize="@dimen/rating" />

    <!-- Rating -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/average_ratings"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/area"
        android:textColor="#D2691E"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"

        android:textSize="@dimen/rating" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cuisine"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/average_ratings"
        android:textColor="#D2691E"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:textSize="@dimen/rating" />

    <!-- Genre -->
   <!-- <TextView
        android:id="@+id/genre"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/rating"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:textColor="@color/genre"
        android:textSize="@dimen/genre" />-->
<!--
    &lt;!&ndash; Release Year &ndash;&gt;
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/releaseYear"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textColor="@color/year"
        android:textSize="@dimen/year" />-->
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Use combination of linear layouts inside your card layout. It will help as card layout itself cant control the arrangement of views

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use CardView child of RelativeLayout

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/ly_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:background="#FEFEFE"
    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
            android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <!-- Restaurant name  -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/area"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/name"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
            android:textColor="#D2691E"/>

        <!-- Rating -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/average_ratings"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/area"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
            android:textColor="#D2691E" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cuisine"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/average_ratings"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
            android:textColor="#D2691E" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: i have to use card view . It will get simple list view. It will get like a 1st image .While i want like a second image see in the second image it is a card view but text are overlapping.

Answer (score 1):

In general your CardView should contain only one Layout - the `RelativeLayout` you've used before. The CardView itself can't position the items as you want them.

If you look at the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html#cardview) you will see that CardView extends FrameLayout which should only contain one child and thus it doesn't give control over the positioning within the CardView.

Answer (score 0):

CardView is like a FrameLayout. Successive items within the cardView in the layout will be placed on top of the previous one.

You can set the layout_gravity to "right" for the TextView.
It wouldn't be a perfect way to do it. So, I suggest encapsulating the TextView inside a Linear Layout with orientation="vertical" and set that LinearLayout's layout_gravity to right.